# How to center the absolute positioned div, inside the relative div, inside the absolute positioned flexContainer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

Let me get this clear. I have a [absolute](/questions/tagged/absolute) positioned `flex container` to create a grid layout. Inside the flex I have a [relative](/questions/tagged/relative) positioned `.tileWrapper` to fill the space (and still keep the layout ) after the `.tile` itself is animated.

When I click the tile ([absolute](/questions/tagged/absolute) positioned), it flips in Y axis and changes size.

I would like to center the `.tile` on the screen when it's flipped. And after I click it again, the center would cancel. I don't even know if it's doable. If not just let me know.

**HTML MARKUP:**

```
<body>

    <div class="flexContainer">
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.<br>
                    Matematyka
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper small">
            <div class="tile matematyka">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tileWrapper big">
            <div class="tile technologie">
                <div class="tileContent front">
                    Tytuł artykułu.
                </div>
                <div class="tileContent back">
                    Treść artykułu.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

/*    outline: 1px solid pink;*/
}
.flexContainer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    padding: 30px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    background: url(../img/background.png);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
       -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
        -ms-flex-direction: column;
            flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
        -ms-flex-line-pack: start;
            align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
}
.tileWrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    margin: 10px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
        -ms-flex-positive: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
        -ms-flex-negative: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
}
.tileWrapper.small {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 100px;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100px;
            flex-basis: 100px;
}
.tileWrapper.big {
    -webkit-flex-basis: 220px;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 220px;
            flex-basis: 220px;
}
.tile {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 10px;
    /*    */
    background : rgb(255, 0, 0);
    /*    */
    border: 0 solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    border-radius: 2px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4), inset 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
            transition: 0.5s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

}
.tile:hover {
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    -webkit-transition:0.2s;
            transition:0.2s;
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
            transform: scale(1.1);
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.tile.flipped {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    z-index: 10;
    border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
    -webkit-transform: perspective(700) rotateY(-180deg);
            transform: perspective(700) rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
            transition: 0.5s;
}


/*Categories*/

.tile.technologie {
    background: rgb(0, 100, 255);
}

/*End Categories*/


.tileContent {
    font-family: 'tahoma';
    color: #fafafa;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px black;
}
.tileContent.front {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-flex-basis: 200px;
        -ms-flex-preferred-size: 200px;
            flex-basis: 200px;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
        -ms-flex-positive: 0;
            flex-grow: 0;
    -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
        -ms-flex-negative: 0;
            flex-shrink: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.tileContent.front.flipped {
    display: none;
}
.tileContent.back {
    display: none;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
            transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
.tileContent.back.flipped {
    display: block;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7g7kqzLd/)

Comment: This is the Inception version of CSS.

Comment: I know you are trying to help, but you've overburdened your question with irrelevant css and HTMl, please trim your answer down and make it as relevant to your question as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that you're looking for the pop-up to be centered in the middle of the page. If that's so, here is what you need to add and remove from your CSS.

```
.flipped{
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 0.9;
  z-index: 10;
  border: 5px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(700) rotateY(-180deg);
  transform: perspective(700) rotateY(-180deg);
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s;
  transition: 0.5s;
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -250px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -150px;
}
```

The left 50% and then negative margin works only because of your set-size on the div, same goes for the top margin. It's now centering in the window.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7g7kqzLd/)

Comment: Thank you, the centering is working perfectly. The only issue is that now the flipped tile is below the rest of the tiles and z-index isn't working. But thank's a lot anyway :)